# Surface area of an Ellipsoid

Tags: regions, geometry

How do I compute the Surface area of an Ellipsoid? I tried this piece of code but the result is wrong

```
a = 0.496
c = 2
x := Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, a, c}]
RegionMeasure[x]

Out[1]= 2.06223
```

When it should actually be ~10. So what is RegionMeasure? And how do I get the surface area?

Comment: Notice the title of the linked topic.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I guess I didn't search enough...